# xQueueGenericReceive error on ESP32 (using FastLED which relies on FreeRTOS) for adapted MeteorRain LED animation

Tags: led, esp32, rgb-led, led-strip

I'm trying to adapt the [MeteorRain animation from Tweaking4All](https://www.tweaking4all.com/hardware/arduino/adruino-led-strip-effects/#LEDStripEffectMeteorRain) to work on segments of [my light string](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08DFH99ZB) (vs using the entire string) and I'm getting an error in FastLED.show() (on a line that is used repeatedly with the same variables before it crashes the "ESP32 DEVKIT V1"). The decode of the ESP32 shows an error in clockless_rmt_esp32.h (which is about as far as I have visibility and ability to troubleshoot the problem.)

Looking through Google results, I find people who have the same error, usually related to memory allocation, but I can't make a connection to FastLED.

The code:

```cpp
#define FASTLED_INTERNAL // add this before including FastLED.h
#include <FastLED.h>

#define LED_PIN     12
#define COLOR_ORDER RGB
#define CHIPSET     WS2811
#define PIXELSECTIONS 2     // there are two segments of christmas lights
#define HORZPIXELS 5        // with 5 lights across connected to
#define VERTPIXELS 12       // 7 lights that hang vertically
#define NUM_LEDS (HORZPIXELS + VERTPIXELS) * PIXELSECTIONS
#define NUM_COLS PIXELSECTIONS
#define NUM_ROWS VERTPIXELS + HORZPIXELS
#define BRIGHTNESS  50

CRGB rawleds[NUM_LEDS];
CRGBSet leds(rawleds, NUM_LEDS);

unsigned long animationsCycleStartTime = millis();
int genericCounter=0;

void setup() {
  // Initialize serial and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(115200);
  // This delay gives the chance to wait for a Serial Monitor without blocking if none is found
  delay(1500); 

  FastLED.addLeds<CHIPSET, LED_PIN, COLOR_ORDER>(rawleds, NUM_LEDS).setCorrection( TypicalLEDStrip );
  FastLED.setBrightness( BRIGHTNESS );
}

void loop() {  
   meteorRain(0xff,0xff,0xff,10, 64, true, 30); 
}

void meteorRain(byte red, byte green, byte blue, byte meteorSize, byte meteorTrailDecay, boolean meteorRandomDecay, int SpeedDelay) {  

  int metaNUM_LEDS = (HORZPIXELS + VERTPIXELS);
  for(int i = 0; i < metaNUM_LEDS+metaNUM_LEDS; i++) {
   
    // fade brightness all LEDs one step
    for(int j=0; j<metaNUM_LEDS; j++) {
      if( (!meteorRandomDecay) || (random(10)>5) ) {
        metaFadeToBlack(j, meteorTrailDecay );        
      }
    }
   
    // draw meteor
    for(int j = 0; j < meteorSize; j++) {
      if( ( i-j <metaNUM_LEDS) && (i-j>=0) ) {
Serial.print("i=" + String(i) + ";j=" + String(j) + ";i-j=" + String(i-j));
        metaSetPixel(i-j, red, green, blue);
Serial.println(" done");
      }
    }
Serial.println("to show");
    FastLED.show();
Serial.println("to wait");
    delay(SpeedDelay);
  }
  genericCounter = (genericCounter>=PIXELSECTIONS) ? 0 : genericCounter+1 ;
}

void fadeToBlack(int ledNo, byte fadeValue) {
 #ifdef ADAFRUIT_NEOPIXEL_H
    // NeoPixel
    uint32_t oldColor;
    uint8_t r, g, b;
    int value;
   
    oldColor = strip.getPixelColor(ledNo);
    r = (oldColor & 0x00ff0000UL) >> 16;
    g = (oldColor & 0x0000ff00UL) >> 8;
    b = (oldColor & 0x000000ffUL);

    r=(r<=10)? 0 : (int) r-(r*fadeValue/256);
    g=(g<=10)? 0 : (int) g-(g*fadeValue/256);
    b=(b<=10)? 0 : (int) b-(b*fadeValue/256);
   
    strip.setPixelColor(ledNo, r,g,b);
 #endif
 #ifndef ADAFRUIT_NEOPIXEL_H
   // FastLED
   leds[ledNo].fadeToBlackBy( fadeValue );
 #endif  
}

// this method transposes the relative pixel to the actual pixel
// for example, on the second pass of loop the code says to use
// pixels 0-16 but since the genericCounter is at 1 this method 
// activates pixels 17-33
void metaSetPixel(int metaPixel, byte red, byte green, byte blue) {
  int actualPixel = (genericCounter * (HORZPIXELS + VERTPIXELS)) + metaPixel;
  setPixel( actualPixel, red, green, blue);
}

void metaFadeToBlack (int metaPixel, byte meteorTrailDecay) {
  int actualPixel = (genericCounter * (HORZPIXELS + VERTPIXELS)) + metaPixel;  
  fadeToBlack(actualPixel, meteorTrailDecay );
}

void setPixel(int Pixel, byte red, byte green, byte blue) {
   // FastLED
   rawleds[Pixel].r = red;
   rawleds[Pixel].g = green;
   rawleds[Pixel].b = blue;
}

void setAll(byte red, byte green, byte blue) {
  for(int i = 0; i < NUM_LEDS; i++ ) {
    setPixel(i, red, green, blue);
  }
  FastLED.show();
}
```

The raw error from Serial console trace:

```
13:50:53.499 -> ⸮⸮�⸮�⸮⸮⸮�@#P#⸮N⸮1h⸮0,cs0_drv:0x00,hd_drv:0x00,wp_drv:0x00
13:50:53.499 -> mode:DIO, clock div:1
13:50:53.499 -> load:0x3fff0018,len:4
13:50:53.499 -> load:0x3fff001c,len:1044
13:50:53.499 -> load:0x40078000,len:10124
13:50:53.499 -> load:0x40080400,len:5856
13:50:53.499 -> entry 0x400806a8
13:50:55.042 -> i=0;j=0;i-j=0 done
13:50:55.042 -> to show
13:50:55.076 -> to wait
13:50:55.076 -> i=1;j=0;i-j=1 done
13:50:55.076 -> i=1;j=1;i-j=0 done
13:50:55.076 -> to show
13:50:55.110 -> to wait
...[snip]...
13:51:01.299 -> to show
13:51:01.299 -> to wait
13:51:01.334 -> i=0;j=0;i-j=0 done
13:51:01.334 -> to show
13:51:01.334 -> /home/runner/work/esp32-arduino-lib-builder/esp32-arduino-lib-builder/esp-idf/components/freertos/queue.c:1443 (xQueueGenericReceive)- assert failed!
13:51:01.334 -> abort() was called at PC 0x40085e41 on core 1
13:51:01.334 -> 
13:51:01.334 -> ELF file SHA256: 0000000000000000
13:51:01.334 -> 
13:51:01.334 -> Backtrace: 0x40084e74:0x3ffb1df0 0x400850e9:0x3ffb1e10 0x40085e41:0x3ffb1e30 0x400d1371:0x3ffb1e70 0x400d171d:0x3ffb1e90 0x400d1801:0x3ffb1ed0 0x400d11bb:0x3ffb1f10 0x400d125b:0x3ffb1f80 0x400d2231:0x3ffb1fb0 0x400860f9:0x3ffb1fd0
13:51:01.372 -> 
13:51:01.372 -> Rebooting...
13:51:01.372 -> ets Jun  8 2016 00:22:57
13:51:01.372 -> 
13:51:01.372 -> rst:0xc (SW_CPU_RESET),boot:0x13 (SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT)
13:51:01.372 -> configsip: 0, SPIWP:0xee
13:51:01.372 -> clk_drv:0x00,q_drv:0x00,d_drv:0x00,cs0_drv:0x00,hd_drv:0x00,wp_drv:0x00
13:51:01.372 -> mode:DIO, clock div:1
13:51:01.372 -> load:0x3fff0018,len:4
13:51:01.408 -> load:0x3fff001c,len:1044
13:51:01.408 -> load:0x40078000,len:10124
13:51:01.408 -> load:0x40080400,len:5856
13:51:01.408 -> entry 0x400806a8
```

The decoded error:

```
Decoding stack results
0x40084e74: invoke_abort at /home/runner/work/esp32-arduino-lib-builder/esp32-arduino-lib-builder/esp-idf/components/esp32/panic.c line 156
0x400850e9: abort at /home/runner/work/esp32-arduino-lib-builder/esp32-arduino-lib-builder/esp-idf/components/esp32/panic.c line 171
0x40085e41: xQueueGenericReceive at /home/runner/work/esp32-arduino-lib-builder/esp32-arduino-lib-builder/esp-idf/components/freertos/queue.c line 1443
0x400d1371: ClocklessController12, 77, 77, 154, (EOrder)10, 0, false, 5>::showPixels(PixelController(EOrder)10, 1, 4294967295u>&) at /Users/jaireaux/Documents/Arduino/libraries/FastLED/platforms/esp/32/clockless_rmt_esp32.h line 288
0x400d171d: CPixelLEDController(EOrder)10, 1, 4294967295u>::show(CRGB const*, int, CRGB) at /Users/jaireaux/Documents/Arduino/libraries/FastLED/controller.h line 408
0x400d1801: CFastLED::show(unsigned char) at /Users/jaireaux/Documents/Arduino/libraries/FastLED/controller.h line 90
0x400d11bb: meteorRain(unsigned char, unsigned char, unsigned char, unsigned char, unsigned char, bool, int) at /Users/jaireaux/Documents/Arduino/libraries/FastLED/FastLED.h line 500
0x400d125b: loop() at /Users/jaireaux/Documents/Arduino/temp/temp.ino line 33
0x400d2231: loopTask(void*) at /Users/jaireaux/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp32/hardware/esp32/1.0.6/cores/esp32/main.cpp line 23
0x400860f9: vPortTaskWrapper at /home/runner/work/esp32-arduino-lib-builder/esp32-arduino-lib-builder/esp-idf/components/freertos/port.c line 143
```